# unable to select information from multiple columns mysql

Tags: mysql, join, select

When i try to run the following query i get a red line under the select, you can assume all table and row names are correct. here is the query:

```
select order_date, date_delivered
from polo_delivery, polo_order inner join polo_order
on polo_delivery.order_id=polo_order.order_id
where order_date = not null and date_delivered = null;
```

do i even need to join the tables or should i be using something like polo_delivery.date_delivered and polo_order.order_date ? thanks

Comment: Do you want join twice with `polo_order`? you put that table twice

Comment: Implicit "comma" join notation is generally out of favor, and has been for the better part of two decades, and mixing implicit and explicit JOIN notations has never been a good idea. ...and you have no join conditions on polo_delivery.

Comment: THat MUST of been giving you an error message !

Answer (score 0):

When you compare information with null information in the where clause, you must to use "x is null or x is not null".

select order_date, date_delivered
from polo_delivery, polo_order inner join polo_order
on polo_delivery.order_id=polo_order.order_id
where order_date is not null and date_delivered is null;

Answer (score 0):

You had extra `polo_order` and to compare null you use `IS`

```
select order_date, date_delivered
from polo_delivery
inner join polo_order
   on polo_delivery.order_id = polo_order.order_id
where order_date IS not null 
  and date_delivered IS null;
```